# Using python __init__.py to import common modules of multiple sripts

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have a python package i'm working on with the below structure:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  script1.py
  script2.py
  script3.py
```

all 3 scripts have common imports for example:

```
import sys
import socket
import subprocess
```

i think it would be more efficient and also 'prettier' if those common imports could be done in the `__init__.py` module rather being imported time after time in each script. I've tried to move those imports to the **init** module , but then they're no longer recognized in their respective python scripts.

What would be the best approach to unify common imports for a python package?

Comment: You could create a subpackage named something like `imports` with just an `__init__.py`, some imports, and an `__all__` defined. Then in your package, use `from .imports import *`.

Comment: So basically another module with just the imports and import that one ?